# Parse Push Notification unable to get notification when app is closed

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, parse-platform, push

i tried parse push service in my android its working good when app is running I could receive notification but when I try sending push notification when app is closed....I cant receive it and it say unfortunately app has stopped
**how can i get notification when app is closed**

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
   PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, OcSongs.class);
   PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
   PushService.subscribe(this, "push", OcSongs.class);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oc_songs);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        AdView ad = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad);
        ad.loadAd(new AdRequest());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
        loadingProgressBar=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal); 
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()

        {
```

**Manifest File**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.freedownload.ocsongs"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" ><uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.freedownload.ocsongs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.freedownload.ocsongs.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />                  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    <activity         android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
  /> 
   <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".splash" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
 <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

<category android:name="com.freedownload.ocsongs" />
</intent-filter>
                  </receiver>
     <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
                   </receiver>

    <activity
         android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:name="OcSongs" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Always replace your API keys with XXXX before posting code. You should revoke those keys for safety.

Answer (score 1):

put this to your manifiest file. it will work..

```
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="your package name.YourCustomReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            <action android:name="your package name.UPDATE_STATUS" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830936/5588656

```
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

// Add your initialization code here
Parse.initialize(this, APP_ID, CL_ID);
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
// Optionally enable public read access.
// defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);



// IF NEEADED
String topic ="YOUR_TOPIC";
System.out.println(topic);
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(topic, new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("com.parse.push",
                    "successfully subscribed ");
        } else {
            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed ", e);
        }
    }
});
```