# Parse notifications on android won't work

Tags: android, parse-platform, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up Parse push notifications on android for some time now.
I followed different tutorials, and I am trying to send the notifications from their web platform, but nothing seems to work. Here is what I have tried so far.

Here is the onCreate method of my Application class

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i("PushNotifications","PARSE initialize");

        Parse.initialize(this, "******************************", "*****************************");
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("PushNotifications","com.parse.push" + " successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                } else {
                    Log.i("PushNotifications","com.parse.push" + " failed to subscribe for push");
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

This is called successfully, as I get the log

> successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.

Also here is some relevant content of my manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.my.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".App"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id" android:value="id:123456789" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!--com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"-->
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.my.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

When I try sending push from Parse website, nothing happens.

As this is not working, I tried implementing my own GcmBroadcastReceiver and changing it in the manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.MyCustomReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.my.app" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And

```
public class MyCustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PushNotifications","MyCustomReceiver");
    }
}
```

Without success.

Then I also tried creating my own ParsePushBroadcastReceiver (by inheriting from ParsePushBroadcastReceiver).

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.CustomParseReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And

```
public class CustomParseReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PushNotifications","PARSE getNotification");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PushNotifications","PARSE onPushOpen");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PushNotifications","PARSE onPushReceive");        
    }

    private JSONObject getDataFromIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("PushNotifications","PARSE getDataFromIntent");            
    }

}
```

It did not work either.

The thing is.. when I create my own GCM BroadcastReceiver and I send a notification from my own server (with some small php script), the notification is successfully received.

I really wonder what's wrong with my implementation of the client side parse notifications system.

Any hint on where the problem might come from?

Comment: Try it with `android:exported="true"` on the broadcast receiver

Comment: It throws an SecurityException: To prevent external tampering to your app's notifications, all receivers registered to handle the following actions must have their exported attributes set to false: com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE, com.parse.push.intent.OPEN, com.parse.push.intent.DELETE

Comment: Your code seems fine. I think you should check for spelling errors. I used Parse and I got stuck for 6 hours just to figure out a spelling error 'Player' 'Players'.

Comment: please change CustomParseReceiver directory and add it into MainActivity package directory, made updation in manifest after adding it.

Comment: Alex, the following line may be causing the issue. You don't need to define the sender id. Removing it should probably fix your issue       

     <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id" android:value="id:123456789" />

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents on this (hope this helps):

I had a similar issue, which I resolved (Explained [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268135/cant-send-push-from-parse-com/30305231#30305231)), so that might be the issue, if not, have a look at my files, at a quick glance they seem to have some small difference from yours, and they work so it's worth a look:

Manifest section:

```
   <!-- for parse pushes -->
    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
            android:name="com.MyStuff.stuff.utils.MyPushReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.MyStuff.stuff" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I implemented my own ParsePushBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyPushReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    protected void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
     //bla bla...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
     // bla bla...
    }

    @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Notification notification = super.getNotification(context, intent);
     // do some stuff with it..
    }

}
```

and my Application class:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{

    private static final String CKey = "***********";
    private static final String AId = "************";

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, AId, CKey);

        //initialized some stuff..

        ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e)
            {
                if (null == e)
                {
                    ParseInstallation install = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                    String token = install.getString("deviceToken");
                   //do some stuff with it...
                }
            }
        });
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
        //some more stuff
    }
```

Hope it sets you on the right path!

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tommy. I copy pasted your code, and replaced package with mine, and unfortunately it did not resolve this issue. About the token you get from the ParseInstallation object, is it the same GCM token as I would get using GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context).register() ?

Comment: AFAIK yes, this is from the parse documents:  'deviceToken: The Apple generated token used for iOS devices, or the token used by GCM to keep track of registration ID (readonly)', but I would read up some more about it in their docs :)

Answer (score 2):

first : did you enable Push Notification Settings From Your project setting

I faced the same problem , finally i delete my project and build new one in Parse , then the problem solved without doing any more things !!!! Why ?? I dont Know ...

and dont forget to get always the latest Parse SDK,, now its Parse-1.9.2.jar